# What's the right way to use vector of vector in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I am trying to find out the right way to use a vector of vector with the following code:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void f(int size) {
      vector<int> v;
      v.reserve(size);

      v[0] = 1; // OK

      vector<vector<int> > vv;
      vv.reserve(size);

      // vv.push_back(v); // everything is OK with this

      vv[0].push_back(1); // Crash
      vv[0] = {1}; // Crash
}

int main() {
    f(3);
}
```

But I wonder why I can't use vector of vector the same way as vector? Why I can't use the member of vv (vector of vector) directly with push_back a vector?

Comment: `v[0] = 1; // OK` It is __not__ ok. The vector has size 0. Use `resize`, not `reserve`.

Comment: Few things, there really isn't a need to pass in a size for vectors, they are dynamic and can just use push_back(). Yes you can always just call resize(size). And what exactly are you trying to do with vv[0].push_back(1). Remember you are trying to push vector of ints (vector<int>) inside a vector. 1 is not a vector<int> but an int.

Comment: @tkausl Thanks. I misused reserve. With resize(), the code works as expected.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI Thanks. Yes, I should use resize. With vv[0].push_back(1), I mean to push_back int 1 to the first vector in vv to ensure vv[0] is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the updated and annotated example. It may help to clarify:

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

void f(int size) 
{
    // don't use using namespace standard at global scope.
    // if you must use it, use it at the tightest possible scope
    // for better, only bring in the names you need
    using std::vector;

    // creates an empty vector with size() == 0 and capacity() == 0
    vector<int> v;

    // this reserves storage, it does not create objects in v or extens its size()
    v.reserve(size);   
    // v.capacity() is now >= size
    // in this example, this step is actually un-necessary because...

    // ... a resize will increase capacity() if necessary
    v.resize(size);

    // there is still possible UB here, if size == 0.
    // we should check for that...
    if (v.size() < 1)
        throw std::out_of_range("size is less than 1");
    v[0] = 1; // This is now OK

    // ...which is essentially equivalent to this...
    v.at(0) = 1;

    // create an empty vector of vectors
    // vv.size() == vv.capacity() == 0
    vector<vector<int> > vv;
    vv.reserve(size);
    // now vv.size() == 0 and vv.capacity() >= size

    // this would result in:
    // vv.size() == 1, vv.capacity() >= max(vv.size(), size);
    // vv.push_back(v); // everything is OK with this

    if(1)
    {
        // at the moment, vv[0] results in UB because .size() is zero
        // so lets's add an entry in vv
        vv.resize(1);
        // vv.size() == 1, vv.capacity() >= max(vv.size(), size);

        // these are now valid
        vv[0].push_back(1); 
        vv[0] = {1}; 
    }
    else
    {
        // this would also be ok
        auto make_vector = [] {
            auto va = vector<int>();
            va.push_back(1);
            return va;
        };
        vv.push_back(make_vector());

        // as would this
        vv.emplace_back(std::vector({1}));
    }
}

int main() {
    f(3);
}
```